# Time Varying Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

What is said time varying magnetic field? I have heard a lot about it and the Internet is not willing to give me any answers. I assume time varying is a qualification, I was reading around here and heard about an induced magnetic field so I take it that is another qualification? What does that mean? Thank you.

Comment: Uhhh...a time varying magnetic field is a magnetic field that varies with time? What are you asking?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Precisely. I just want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time-varying means that as time, $t$, increases, the magnetic field changes. One of the more common representations is a [sinusoidal wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine):

[image]

(image from the linked Wikipedia page). Though the image above says $x$, the relation between $x$ and $\sin(x)$ is what is important.

With magnetic fields, [Maxwell's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations),
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf E=\frac\rho{\epsilon_0} \quad \nabla\cdot\mathbf B=0 \\
\nabla\times\mathbf E=0 \quad \nabla\times\mathbf B=\mu_0\mathbf J
$$
(where $\mathbf E$ is the electric field, $\mathbf B$ the magnetic field, $\mathbf J$ the [current density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_density), $\epsilon_0$ the [vacuum permittivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity_of_free_space), $\rho$ the charge density, and $\mu_0$ the [vacuum permeability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_of_free_space)) then become
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf E=\frac\rho{\epsilon_0} \quad \nabla\cdot\mathbf B=0 \\
\nabla\times\mathbf E=\color{blue}{-\frac{\partial\mathbf B}{\partial t}} \quad \nabla\times\mathbf B=\mu_0\mathbf J+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial\mathbf E}{\partial t}}
$$
where the blue-colored terms show that the two fields induce each other when changing in space and/or time.

Answer (score 0):

Time varying magnetic field $\vec{B}(t)$ or any quantity. It means which varies with time.

Let us understand by an example:

$\vec{B}(t) = B_{0}f(t)\hat{B}$.

It means that, $f(t)$ is different from a time $t_2$ which is either before or after $t_1$, if $t_1$ and $t_2$ are distinct. This changing behaviour may arise because of some external regulations.

My simultaneous use before and after is showing that in either case quantity is different.

Comment: What is $\hat{B}$?

Comment: @KyleKanos, Direction of $\vec{B}$ denoting it by a unit vector.